# Java - createImageIcon() not recognized in code?

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I keep getting an error that createImageIcon() is not recognized as an available function. Not sure why this is occuring, as I feel like I have loaded the libraries that I need for it.

```
ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif","this is a caption");
```

I've tried using different arguments, etc., but can't seem to figure it out.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class main extends JFrame {

    public main() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu Menu_File = new JMenu("TEST MENU");
        JMenu Menu_File_New = new JMenu("New");
        ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif","this is a caption");
        Menu_File.add(Menu_File_New);
        JMenuItem Menu_File_New_Project = new JMenuItem("Project...");
        JMenuItem Menu_File_New_Burrito = new JMenuItem("Burrito...");
        JMenuItem Menu_File_New_Cookie = new JMenuItem("Cookie...");
        JMenuItem Menu_File_New_Other = new JMenuItem("Other...");
        Menu_File_New.add(Menu_File_New_Project);
        Menu_File_New.add(Menu_File_New_Burrito);
        Menu_File_New.add(Menu_File_New_Cookie);
        Menu_File_New.add(Menu_File_New_Other);
        JMenuItem Menu_File_Open = new JMenuItem("Open...");
        JMenuItem Menu_File_Save = new JMenuItem("Save");
        JMenuItem Menu_File_SaveAs = new JMenuItem("Save As...");
        JMenuItem Menu_File_Reload= new JMenuItem("Reload");
        Menu_File.add(Menu_File_Open);
        Menu_File.add(Menu_File_Save);
        Menu_File.add(Menu_File_SaveAs);
        Menu_File.add(Menu_File_Reload);
        Menu_File.addSeparator();
        JMenuItem Menu_File_Screenshot = new JMenuItem("Take Screenshot");
        Menu_File.add(Menu_File_Screenshot);
        Menu_File.addSeparator();
        JMenuItem Menu_File_Exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        Menu_File.add(Menu_File_Exit);
        menuBar.add(Menu_File);
        JMenu Menu_Edit = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu Menu_Windows = new JMenu("Windows");
        JMenu Menu_Mode = new JMenu("Mode");
        JMenu Menu_Help = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(Menu_Edit);
        menuBar.add(Menu_Windows);
        menuBar.add(Menu_Mode);
        menuBar.add(Menu_Help);

        main frame = new main();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar); // Create menu and associate with frame
        frame.setTitle("3DAirspace");
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        //frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should it actually be:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/middle.gif","this is a caption");
```

so that you're calling the constructor for a new ImageIcon object?

Answer (score 5):

The method you're calling is not in your class.

In the Java tutorial [How to use icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html), there is this example method of the same name, that you can copy into your class.

```
/** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path,
                                       String description) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code work for me :

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1",new ImageIcon("youricon.gif"));
```

Answer (score -2):

Would this work?

```
ImageIcon icon = new createImageIcon("images/middle.gif","this is a caption");
```